# conditional validation of textbox based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on asp.net mvc website and I have 4 `dropdowns` and 4 `textboxes` like this:

```
dialprefix1   callfromnumber1
dialprefix2   callfromnumber2
dialprefix3   callfromnumber3
dialprefix4   callfromnumber4
```

I want to group each row so that if value in `dialprefix1` is `44` then `callfromnumber1` has length 10. Means I want to perform validation of `textbox` based on `dropdown` and there are multiple rows.

I have used this to allow numeric in textboxes

```
$(".phone").keydown(function (event) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
    if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    } else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

and I am validating length like this:

```
$("#DefaultCallFrom1").keypress(function () {
    if ($("#Dialprefix1").val() == "44") {
        if (this.value.substring(0, 1) == "0" && this.value.length == "10") {
            displayAlertMessage("You can not enter more characters");
            this.value.length <= 10
        }
        else {
            displayAlertMessage("You can not enter more characters");
            this.value.length <= 9
        }
    }
})

$("#DefaultCallFrom2").keypress(function () {
    if ($("#Dialprefix2").val() == "44") {
        if (this.value.substring(0, 1) == "0")
            return this.value.length <= 10
        else
            return this.value.length <= 9
    }
})
```

1) I want to combine these based on class all textbox has class = phone and all dropdowns has class dialprefix.

2). I want to make sure that number starts with 0,1,2,7,8 if related dropdown selected value is 44

The markup looks like this:

```
<td style="padding-left: 1px">

<input type="text" value="1" readonly="readonly" name="srNo" id="srNo" disabled="disabled" class="tiny" style="text-align:right">
<select name="Dialprefix1" id="Dialprefix1" class="dialprefix">
    <option value="44">+44</option>
    <option value="001">+001</option>
    <option value="11" selected="selected">+11</option>
    <option value="12">+12</option>
    <option value="13">+13</option>
</select>

<span class="watermark_container" style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
<span class="watermark" style="position: absolute; display: block; font-family: MS Shell Dlg; font-size: 13.3333px; color: rgb(153, 153, 153); left: 4px; top: 0px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; text-align: left; pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.6;">
    Click here to add your phone number.
</span>
<input type="text" value="" title="Click here to add your phone number." name="DefaultCallFrom1" id="DefaultCallFrom1" class="textarea normal jq_watermark phone" autocomplete="off" data-jq-watermark="processed">
</span>
<br>

<input type="text" value="2" readonly="readonly" name="srNo" id="srNo" disabled="disabled" class="tiny" style="text-align:right">
<select name="Dialprefix2" id="Dialprefix2" class="dialprefix">
    <option value="44">+44</option>
    <option value="001">+001</option>
    <option value="11" selected="selected">+11</option>
    <option value="12">+12</option>
    <option value="13">+13</option>
</select>

<span class="watermark_container" style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
<span class="watermark" style="position: absolute; display: block; font-family: MS Shell Dlg; font-size: 13.3333px; color: rgb(153, 153, 153); left: 4px; top: 0px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; text-align: left; pointer-events: none;">
    Click here to add your phone number.
</span>
<input type="text" value="" title="Click here to add your phone number." name="DefaultCallFrom2" id="DefaultCallFrom2" class="textarea normal jq_watermark phone" autocomplete="off" data-jq-watermark="processed">
</span>
<br>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having problems with? And what is your question?

Comment: @FelixKling, I just added the markup as well.

Comment: can set up traverse to find matching elements but markup doesn't show `DefaultCallFrom1` or `DefaultCallFrom2`

Comment: @charlietfl how to setup traverse ? there is a textbox next of each dropdown. sorry i missed that in markup.

Comment: Exactly what does the code `this.value.length <= 9` do?

Comment: @ATOzTOA it makes sure that if related dropdown has value 44 then related textbox can have 10 characters maximum

Answer (score 0):

Give each of the inputs a common class ( they aren't shown in markup). There are several ways to approach matching `input` to it's corresponding `select` such as using `prev()` or `next()` if they are side by side in the html tree with no other eleemnts like `<br>` separating them.

Learning the various ways to traverse the html tree will help both simplifying jQuery code and creating markup that  makes for easier traverals. Note that no ID is required anyyhwere in following.

I will use `index()` to match them since markup is unknown . I am  using `DefaultCallFrom` as className for `input`.

```
var $inputs= $(".DefaultCallFrom"), $selects=$('.dialprefix');

$inputs.keypress(function () {
     /* get index of active input and use to match select*/
     var idx= $inputs.index( this ), $sel=$selects.eq( idx );
    if ($sel.val() == "44") {
        if (this.value.substring(0, 1) == "0" && this.value.length == "10") {
            displayAlertMessage("You can not enter more characters");
            this.value.length <= 10
        }
        else {
            displayAlertMessage("You can not enter more characters");
            this.value.length <= 9
        }
    }
})
```

API reference

http://api.jquery.com/index/

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: @charlieftfl, It works great. only problem is that when a number is typed and i try to delete it or change it doesnt allow me to change it

Comment: I only created the traverse... I didn't check or test your validation code... is that the issue at  hand? If so create a demo in jsfiddle.net that can be used to test

Comment: @charlieft, can I do this task on two events ? like  $inputs.keypress and  $inputs.click  and $selects.click?

Comment: would use `change` event of select  http://api.jquery.com/change/ Not sure what UI would want to use for select validation if number doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your code. Try this instead of the `$("#DefaultCallFrom1").keypress(function ()` :

```
$(".phone").keypress(function(evt) {
    // Find the index
    index = ($(this).attr('id')).split("DefaultCallFrom")[1];

    // Check Dialprefix
    if ($("#Dialprefix" + index).val() == "44") {
        // 0 prefix
        if (this.value[0] == 0) {
            if(this.value.length == 10) {
                alert("You can not enter more characters...");
                evt.preventDefault();
            } 
        } else {
            if(this.value.length == 9) {
                alert("You can not enter more characters...");
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
});
```